# Minimizing $\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}(H^3)\operatorname{Tr}H}$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Suppose $H$ is a diagonal positive definite $d\times d$ matrix with $\operatorname{Tr}(H)=1$.

I'm interested in $H$ which minimizes the following:

$$J=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}(H^3)\operatorname{Tr}H}$$

I can use numerical [optimizer](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/forum-step1-minimizer.nb) to solve it and get something like this on diagonal for $d=40$.

[image]

Largest value is $0.239376$ and remaining mass is split equally among remaining dimensions.

What is the solution in the limit of $d\to \infty$?

Motivation: minimizing $J$ gives shape of quadratic which is hardest to minimize with a single step of gradient descent.

Comment: Is there a reason you are interested in this particular ratio?

Comment: Yes, I give the reason under "Motivation". A bit more detail is [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/42549/18786)

Comment: Somewhat interesting fact, the minimal (positive definite) H occurs when $$\frac{4d}{3} = \frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)}{\operatorname{Tr}(H^3)}$$

Comment: In other words, the problem is to minimize $\frac{(\lambda_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_d^2)^2}{(\lambda_1^3+\cdots+\lambda_d^3)(\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_d)}$ for positive reals $\lambda_i>0$.

Comment: @KentaS the partial derivatives only get you as far as what I commented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We omit the trivial case $d=1$ and assume that $d\ge2$. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d$ be the eigenvalues of $H$ and let $S_k=\sum_i\lambda_i^k$. At the maximum point of $J=\frac{S_2^2}{S_1S_3}$, we have
$$
0=\frac{dJ}{d\lambda_i}
=\frac{2S_2'S_2S_1S_3-S_2^2(S_1'S_3+S_1S_3')}{(S_1S_3)^2}
=\frac{S_2}{(S_1S_3)^2}\left[2S_2'S_1S_3-S_2(S_1'S_3+S_1S_3')\right],
$$
where $S_k'$ means $\frac{dS_k}{d\lambda_i}$. Therefore
$$
0=2S_2'S_1S_3-S_2(S_1'S_3+S_1S_3')=4\lambda_i S_1S_3-S_2(S_3+3S_1\lambda_i^2),
$$
meaning that *every* $\lambda_i$ is a root of the quadratic equation
$$
3S_1S_2x^2-4S_1S_3x+S_2S_3=0.\tag{1}
$$
It follows that $H$ has at most two different eigenvalues. Since $J(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)=J(c\lambda_1,\ldots,c\lambda_d)$ for every scalar $c$ and the optimal $H$ is *not* a scalar multiple of the identity matrix (because $J_{H=I}=1$ is greater than $\frac{8}{9}$, the optimal value of $J$ when $d=2$), we may assume that the optimal $H$ is equal to $\lambda I_p\oplus I_{d-p}$ for some $0<\lambda\ne1$ and $p\ge\frac{d}{2}$. Thus $S_k=p\lambda^k+(d-p)$ and equation $(1)$ is satisfied by $x=1$ and $x=\lambda$. Substitute $x=1$ into $(1)$, we get $3S_1S_2-4S_1S_3+S_2S_3=0$. So, at $x=\lambda$, equation $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{align}
&3S_1S_2(\lambda^2-1)-4S_1S_3(\lambda-1)=0,\\
&4S_3=3S_2(\lambda+1),\tag{2}\\
&4\left[p\lambda^3+(d-p)\right]=3\left[p\lambda^2+(d-p)\right](\lambda+1),\\
&p\lambda^3-3p\lambda^2-3(d-p)\lambda+(d-p)=0,\tag{3}\\
&S_3=3\lambda S_1.\tag{4}\\
\end{align}
$$
Let us investigate the behaviours of the roots of equation $(3)$. For any $1\ge r>0$, define $f_r(x)=x^3-3x^2-3rx+r$. Since $f_r(0)=r>0$, $f_r(1)=-2-2r<0$, $f_r(\sqrt{3r})=f_r(3)=-8r<0$ and $f(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to+\infty$, the cubic equation $f_r(x)=0$ has one negative root, one positive root in $(0,\min\{1,\sqrt{3r}\})$ and one positive root in $(3,\infty)$. Now let $1\ge r>s>0$ and let $x_r,x_s$ be two positive roots of $f_r(x)=0$ and $f_s(x)=0$ respectively. Then
$$
\begin{align}
0&=f_r(x_r)-f_s(x_s)\\
&=(x_r^3-3x_r^2-3rx_r+r)-(x_s^3-3x_s^2-3sx_s+s)\\
&=(x_r^3-x_s^3)-3(x_r^2-x_s^2)-3rx_r+3sx_s+(r-s)\\
&=(x_r-x_s)(x_r^2+x_rx_s+x_s^2)-3(x_r-x_s)(x_r+x_s)-3r(x_r-x_s)-3(r-s)x_s+(r-s)\\
&=(x_r-x_s)\left[ (x_r^2-3x_r) +(x_s^2-3x_s) + (x_rx_s-3r) \right] - 3(r-s)(x_s-1)\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
x_r-x_s
=\frac{3(r-s)(x_s-1)}{(x_r^2-3x_r) +(x_s^2-3x_s) + (x_rx_s-3r)}.
$$
Note that the RHS is nonnegative when $x_r$ and $x_s$ both lie inside $(0,\min\{1,\sqrt{3r}\})$ or $(3,\infty)$. It follows that both the minimum and maximum positive roots of $f_r(x)=0$ increase with $r$. Now, from $(2)^2/(4)$, we obtain
$$
J=\frac{S_2^2}{S_3S_1}=\frac{16\lambda}{3(\lambda+1)^2}.
$$
Since $g(\lambda)=\frac{16\lambda}{3(\lambda+1)^2}$ is strictly increasing on $(0,1)$ and strictly decreasing on $(1,\infty)$, the optimisation problem now reduces to finding $J=\min\left\{g(\lambda'),g(\lambda'')\right\}$ where $\lambda'$ is the minimum positive root $(3)$ when $p=d-1$ (i.e., when $r=\frac{d-p}{p}$ is minimal) while $\lambda''$ is the maximum positive root of $(3)$ when $p=1$ (i.e., when $r=\frac{d-p}{p}$ is maximal). By Cardano's formula, we have
$$
\lambda''=\frac{1}{\lambda'}
=1+2\operatorname{Re}\sqrt[3]{d(1+i\sqrt{d-1})}
=1+2\sqrt{d}\cos\left(\frac13\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\right)\right).
$$
Since $g(x)=g(\frac{1}{x})$ for all $x>0$, the optimal $J$ is simply $g(\lambda'')$, while the optimal unnormalised $H$ is $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda'',1,\ldots,1)$ and the optimal (trace-)normalised $H$ is $\operatorname{diag}(\frac{\lambda''}{\lambda''+d-1},\frac{1}{\lambda''+d-1},\ldots,\frac{1}{\lambda''+d-1})$.

Comment: very informative and nice to read, thanks!